# Error building Apache Mesos

Tags: maven, ubuntu-14.04, mesos

I've been trying to build Apache Mesos on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. I ran the following commands:

```
1) cd mesos
2) ./bootstrap
3) mkdir build
4) cd build
5) ../configure
6) make
```

When I run make I get the following error:

```
Building mesos-0.21.0.jar ...
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]   
[ERROR]   The project org.apache.mesos:mesos:0.21.0 (/home/eejya/mesos/build/src/java/mesos.pom) has 1 error
[ERROR]     Non-parseable POM /home/eejya/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom: Expected root element 'project' but found 'HTML' (position: START_TAG seen <HTML>... @1:6)  @ /home/eejya/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/11/apache-11.pom, line 1, column 6 -> [Help 2]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ProjectBuildingException
[ERROR] [Help 2] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/ModelParseException
make[1]: *** [java/target/mesos-0.21.0.jar] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/eejya/mesos/build/src'
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

I also tried to run the command mvn -e without any target and I got the following error message:

```
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.195s
[INFO] Finished at: Fri Sep 19 02:46:02 IST 2014
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/105M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.NoGoalSpecifiedException: No goals have been specified for this build. You must specify a valid lifecycle phase or a goal in the format <plugin-prefix>:<goal> or <plugin-group-id>:<plugin-artifact-id>[:<plugin-version>]:<goal>. Available lifecycle phases are: validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy, pre-clean, clean, post-clean, pre-site, site, post-site, site-deploy.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:104)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

Could someone point out the problem here?

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your apache-11.pom is invalid. Open it up and verify the contents. Mine starts with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
Apache License Blob
-->

<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" ...
```

It looks like you've got an html file there instead (perhaps a 404 error page?). If so, try removing your `~/.m2/repository/org/apache/apache/11/` directory and running `make` again. The build process should pull down a new pom.